# How can I add in this circles a select of type radio on the top line?

Tags: html, select, margin, geometry

```
<svg height="334.4" width="334.4">
    <circle cx="167.2" cy="167.2" r="134" stroke="#00ffff" stroke-width=4 fill="#e6ffff" />
    <text text-anchor="middle" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1px" dy=".3em">
        <tspan x="50%" y="25%" dy="1.2em">1200% DAILY FOR 40 DAYS</tspan>
    </text>
    <text text-anchor="middle" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5px" dy=".3em">
        <tspan x="50%" y="35%" dy="1.2em">Noko 4</tspan>
        <tspan x="50%" y="45%" dy="1.2em">Spent Amount ($):</tspan>
        <tspan x="50%" y="55%" dy="1.2em">Min 60.000,00 - Max 260.000,00</tspan>
        <tspan x="50%" y="65%" dy="1.2em">Daily Profit: 1200%</tspan>
        <tspan x="50%" y="75%" dy="1.2em">No deposit</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

How can I add in a circle a select of type radio on the first line?

Comment: I think the question is quite broad. Can you give a context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using positions, we can do the trick. 
I have wrapped your entire SVG inside a div and applied following CSS.

```
.parentDiv {
    display: inline-block
    position: relative;
}

.radioButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}
```

It's actually outside SVG element. But positions make it look like it's inside. [Check out this pen](https://codepen.io/ajayvarghese/pen/gKYeQy).

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the radio button using `<foreignObject>`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="334.4" width="334.4">
  <circle cx="167.2" cy="167.2" r="134" stroke="#00ffff" stroke-width="4" fill="#e6ffff" />
  <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%" x="40%" y="15%">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <label>SELECT <input type="radio"/></label>
    </body>
  </foreignObject>
  <text text-anchor="middle" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1px" dy=".3em">
    <tspan x="50%" y="25%" dy="1.2em">1200% DAILY FOR 40 DAYS</tspan>
  </text>
  <text text-anchor="middle" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5px" dy=".3em">
    <tspan x="50%" y="35%" dy="1.2em">Noko 4</tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" y="45%" dy="1.2em">Spent Amount ($):</tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" y="55%" dy="1.2em">Min 60.000,00 - Max 260.000,00</tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" y="65%" dy="1.2em">Daily Profit: 1200%</tspan>
    <tspan x="50%" y="75%" dy="1.2em">No deposit</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Adding the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` namespace defines the foreign object as html.

Comment: Didn't know about that foreignObject tag. Thanks mate :)

Comment: I fixed it. You have to include the namespace for the foreignObject.